# WordPress child theme not showing

Tags: php, wordpress

I just created a child theme and activated it.But when I visit the page,it's completely blank.

In the display is the themes folder where I have my parent theme and the child,then below is the site details from the parent style.css which I simply copied and pasted to the child stylesheet.

[image]

functions.php looks like this:

```
<?php
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

    $parent_style = 'parent-style';

    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array( $parent_style ),
        wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
?>
```

As the photo shows,the theme is active.

[image]

How can I create a child theme and make it visible as the parent theme?

Comment: Completely blank page is maybe a result of an error. Is `WP_DEBUG` `true`?

Comment: @Andy Tschiersch.Yes it is set to true.
I created the child theme previously using the twenty sixteen theme,wp-debug was set to false and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't just copy the parent style, it's better to create a new one and import the parent's. You also need to specify the Template as the parent theme. Try using this:

```
/*
    Theme Name:   Sidimaag Child Theme
    Theme URI:    http://underscores.me
    Description:  Sidimaag Child Theme
    Author:       mytheme
    Author URI:   http://mytheme.co.za
    Template:     sidimaag
    Version:      1.0.0
    License:      GNU General Public License v2 or later
    License URI:  http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
    Tags:         light, dark, two-columns, right-sidebar, responsive-layout, accessibility-ready
    Text Domain:  sidimaag
    */
```

Then you can use @import to import the parent's style like this:

```
@import url('path_to_parent_theme/style.css');
```

Comment: I did that yes. Now I am using the import as you advised instead of the functions.php but it does work as well.
@import url('../sidimaag/style.css');

It is funny because previously,I created the child theme using the twenty sixteen theme with the same procedures and it worked so I really don't know how to fix this.

Comment: For enqueuing the parent's style within your functions.php, use this in your child functions.php file:                                                        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'sidimaag_child_theme_enqueue_styles' );
function sidimaag_child_theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'sidimaag', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
}  If you can provide access to your WP, I can help you.

Comment: @ I.T. I wish I could give you access. am working on the localhost.

Comment: Ok, no worries. Did you add the Template: sidimaag in your child's style.css as I suggested before? Creating a child theme is very simple, the child theme should be visible with only the style.css file. Please check your paths and check this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wEYSqEBZHRE

Answer (score 0):

To save your life,just install themify plugin.
It is very straightforward. You install the plugin. Go to:
Appearance -> Themes
When you see your themes,hover over it and you'll see Theme Details. Click on it and then look for the button named: create child theme..name your theme,click ok...and vuala!!!